# Replace string in Retrofit GET request in Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I am trying to replace String in my GET url. Query looks as follow:

```
@GET("read/something/Books?$filter=(substringof('{filter}',Description)+or+substringof('{filter}',Code)+or+substringof('{filter}',Title)+or+substringof('{filter}',Barcode))")
    Call<ApiResponse<Book>> getFilteredBooks(@Path("filter") String filter);
```

So I want to replace {filter} with dynamic string.
I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "$filter=(substringof('{filter}',Description)+or+substringof('{filter}',Code)+or+substringof('{filter}',Title)+or+substringof('{filter}',Barcode))" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

I couldn't find any other suitable annotation that would work as expected.

Comment: For starters the error message is telling you what the problem is.. You need to use @Query and not @Path. `filter` is a query param and not a path param

Answer (score 1):

You should use query parameters, like:

```
@GET("read/something/Books")
    Call<ApiResponse<Book>> getFilteredBooks(@Query("$filter") String filter);
```

This will create url like `.../read/something/Books?$filter={parameter you sent}`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know I can use @Query. But it looks very cumbersome. I need to call `getFilteredBooks("(substringof('SCRUM',Description)+or+substringof('SCRUM',Code)+or+substringof('SCRUM',Title)+or+substringof('SCRUM',Barcode))")`
It is not flexible when I call it multiple times in many places and perhaps I want to add some another filtering field in the future. There is really no way to simply replace one string with another string in the url?

Comment: OK, i figured out what you are trying to do, but these long string requests confused me. So you can build up your query parameter, you can make a method `buildQueryParam(String filter) { return " (substringof('+ filter + ',Description)} + ...` which sets filter in all places. This methods then returns proper string for query param: `getFilteredBooks(buildQueryParam("SCRUM"))`